# behaviour of ngIf and property binding in angular

Tags: angular

```
      <myview [myVariable]=myVariable  *ngIf="myVariable">
      </myview>
```

I have the above component template defined which binds myVariable property to myVariable prop of myview component. If there is a change in myVariable, is the myview component supposed to reload(constructor or ngOnInit). Its not in my environment and thus confused if this is the expected behaviour. The component is getting instantiated just once and I would like it to refresh its values after any change to myVariable in the parent component.

Comment: are there any console errors? also `[myVariable]=myVariable` should be `[myVariable]="myVariable"` (typo?) Also `ngOnit` should be called once when instantiated, and the variable will be bound and updated when changed from the  parent

Comment: no errors in console. corrected typo, but looks like angular is lenient there and allows binding without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get that event in `ngOnChanges` here is the example.

you need to write `ngOnChanges` in your `myview` component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Input() myVariable: any; 

class myViewComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void { 
   console.log(changes.myVariable); // here you will get the updated value of myVariable 
  }
}
```

**you parent component html**

```html
 <myview [myVariable]="myVariable"  *ngIf="myVariable">
 </myview>
```

Comment: so inside ngOnChanges, if I assign the updated result to some instance variable, will the view for myView change/update accordingly ?